# Atmega328p low voltage

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, voltage-level, fuses

I am using atmega328p in my PCB prototype, due to some reason I can use only 4 volt for power supply.
My question is that
"How to run atmega328P through 4 voltage"

Comment: Have you read the datasheet?

Comment: Your question is rather fuzzy: I could well answer it as "Connect the +4V to Vcc pin and 0V to the GND pin", that would be correct. What is your **specific** question?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't be a problem. The minimal voltage required to run at 16MHz is 3.8 Volt. No extra steps required.

Answer (score 0):

Having only a 4V power supply, you can insert a boost converter to step up the voltage to 5V and then supply it to VCC of atmega328p